# Does “system image” include program files installed on a different partition?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I like to install program files on a separate partition (Virtual partition P: for instance). If I do a system image will it copy those program files too?

Edit: I'm using Easus Todo Backup. System is Win 10. I read this someplace on a Windows Forum - "Image backup (and restore) both C and D together - to keep them and the registry synced".. In my case will be C and P. Will that work?

Comment: are you using the windows backup software or another program? The answer is almost certianly no, but without knowing the product its impossible to say for sure. Backup images are generally 1-to-1 to volumes, which allows them to be restored without overwriting user data stored elsewhere, or restored in situations where a secondary disk is unavailable. An image is called an image because it is an exact picture of the bits on a hard disk at a low level, so an image should not contain data that is not stored physically in the volume it is an image of.

Comment: @FrankThomas Volumes are not physical constructs. They are logical sections of a physical disk.

Comment: exactly. have you ever noticed that volumes must be contigious in physical address layout, and are supposed to be aligned to begin and end on the address of a sector boundrary? that allows a device with low level access to the disk to read the partition table, and find the contiguous range of physical addresses within that volume. Note that in this case "volume" is used to represent a partition based storage object, be it a primary partition containing a filesystem directly or a logical volume within an extended partition.

Comment: Based on the screen shots here: http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/backup-system-partition.htm the backup job is only of the C:\ drive. your best bet is probably to schedule a backup of both C and P on a consecutive schedule, with similar retention rules.

Comment: In my case will need to backup C and P by using Partition Backup. Will that work to restore my OS and program files in event of crash, or will I need to reinstall all programs?

Comment: I'd do a system backup of C and a partition backup of P.

Comment: @Coffee If you backup both partitions simultaneously, and restore them both to the same backup state, then yes, you will get a consistent, older state when you restore. If you want to backup/restore them independently, then it depends; If you have programs installed on the `P:` drive, then you certainly need to synchronize the backup & restore actions for the two partitions.

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on what program you do to image your hard drive, and what options you specify.

Most programs I've used will copy a single partition separately, rather than the entire hard disk; but it is a simple matter to copy & backup the extra partition as well as the system partition.

A few may have the option to back up an entire hard drive at a time. Of course, for partitions on separate hard disks, the answer is still, No, but you can back them up separately as well.